# javascript replace all \\ with \

Tags: javascript, string

In Javascript (Node) (fs module), when reading from a txt file, it converts all backslashes to double-backslashes, so that they don't accidentally escape the characters following them.
however, having \n ACTUALLY escape the character n might be desirable in some cases.
I could do something like this:

```
str = str.replace(/\\n/g,"\n").replace(/\\t/g,"\t")... etc
```

but if there's a function that does this automatically, this is just unneccesary repetition.
i've done heaps of research, and still can't find a solution to this problem

Comment: `when reading from a txt file, it converts all backslashes to double-backslashes` No it doesn't. `so that they don't accidentally escape the characters following them.` Thats not how escaping works. Escaping applies to strings in your source code, not to what you read in through IO.

Comment: When you read a file, it doesn't actually auto-convert the backslash characters (as far as I know). When you `console.log` it, though, the console will escape them for you so that you don't get confused on whether that `\n` is a newline or a literal `\n`. tkausl beat me to comment that... 

Comment: Please post the code that reads the file into `str` and also the code that does display `str` somewhere